# Need to create an unnumbered 'conclusion' environment

Tags: numbering, amsthm, ntheorem, newtheorem

I need to write `conclusion` in my thesis without a number. I used

```
\newtheorem{conclusion}{Conclusion}
\begin{conclusion}
\end{conclusion}
```

and got as a output `Conclusion 1`; however, I need only `Conclusion`.

Answer (score 6):

How to create unnumbered theorem-like environments depends strongly on whether your documents loads the `amsthm` or the `ntheorem` package (or neither).

- If you work with the `amsthm` package, use the `\newtheorem*` macro to create unnumbered  theorem-like environments.

  ```
  \newtheorem{conclusion}{Conclusion}
  \newtheorem*{concnonum}{Conclusion}
  ```
- If you work with the `ntheorem` package, issue the instruction `\theoremstyle{nonumberplain}` to switch to the unnumbered theorem style; then, create further, unnumbered theorem-like environments using `\newtheorem` directives. E.g.,

  ```
  \newtheorem{conclusion}{Conclusion}
  \theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
  \newtheorem{concnonum}{Conclusion}
  ```

Answer (score 5):

Mico's answer is quite nice if what you want is a theorem-like environnent. But for a thesis, a conclusion can be an unnumbered section (or subsection, depending of the text), imho. So that I would do something like:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\section*{Conclusion}
\lipsum{1-2}
\end{document}
```